# SQL Server blob corruption

Tags: sql-server

We have a system where we store timeseries data in BLOB fields of an SQL Server 2008 R2

The table looks like this (simplified, some columns skipped):

```
CREATE TABLE T_TimeSeries (
ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Tag varchar(80) NOT NULL,
Count int NOT NULL,
data varbinary(max) NULL)
```

I have a python process for continuously appending to 'data' and incrementing 'Count'.
An invariant is that `len(data)==4*Count` should always hold. I have that invariant as an assertion in the code. Once in a while (every two months or so), this assertion fails - where `len(data)` will be one byte short of the expected value.

In an attempt to "fix" the data and let my process continue without assertion violation, I have attempted to append a single zero byte. But that increases the length of the blob by two!!

Here are the details of what I do:

```
select TSMode, 4*count as count4, len(data) as len 
from T_TimeSeries where Tag='<tag-of-the-affected-row>'
```

This yields:

```
count4  len
233776  233775
```

Then I append the zero byte, like this:

```
update T_TimeSeries set data.Write(0x00, NULL, 0) where Tag='<tag-of-the-affected-row>'
```

and `SELECT` again, to get:

```
count4  len
233776  233777
```

Isn't this clear evidence of a bug in SQL Server? I append one byte, and the length jumps from 233775 to 233777.
I can consistently repeat it - removing one byte with data.write(0x, 233776, 1) to get back to length 233775.

The normal data write pattern of my process is not always in linear order - sometimes we insert in the middle, replacing existing data. But no matter what steps we perform, I would think we should never end up in this state - it looks to me like a database corruption.

Do you agree?

I would like to know if it is indeed an SQL Server bug, or me doing something wrong, because it will determine how we should fix this situation :-)

Comment: What happens if you count the length using the `DATALENGTH` function instead of `LEN`? [DATALENGTH reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

Comment: Oh, DATALENGTH yields the expected result: 233776.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEN` converts `varbinary` to a `varchar` and measures the string length. That excludes [any trailing blanks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) which may lead to the discrepancy. Adding a zero-byte to the end of the binary will increase its length by the number of trailing blanks plus one.

So it's not a bug. As Dan pointed out, use `DATALENGTH`.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Thanks, Tim. :-)
I have seen the assert violation very rarely. Maybe that's because my blob is a direct memory copy of an array of IEEE float32, little endian. It seems that it is rare that such an encoding will end with 0x20

Comment: Yes, in little endian encoding, the final byte covers the IEEE float32 exponent. The encoded number in this case is around 3e-19. Only numbers of roughly this magnitude will have a final 0x20 byte in the encoding, and thus cause LEN to give me the wrong byte-count.